# Deleting specific elements from an array

Tags: java, arrays

Complete the implementation of one public static methods

```
greaterThan()
```

Return type: `int[]`

Parameter list: one `int[]` `array` parameter list, and one `int` parameter `v`.

Action: Returns a new array whose element values are those values in  `int[]` array parameter  list that are greater than  int parameter  `v`.
Consider the following code segment

```
int[] array = { 7, -1, -4, 2, 1, 6, 1, -3, 2, 0, 2, -7, 2, 8 };

int[] g1 = Determine.greaterThan( array, 2 );

int[] g2 = Determine.greaterThan( array, 7 );

int[] g3 = Determine.greaterThan( array, 9 );
```

causes array variables

`g1` to represent a 3-element array with element values `7`, `6`, and `8`

`g2`, and to represent a 1-element array with element value `8`

`g3` to represent a `0`-element array

This is what I have so far:

```
public class Determine {

// method greaterThan(): reutrns new int[] array whose element values are the ones
// in list greater than v 
public static int[] greaterThan( int[] list, int v){

    int n = list.length;
    int[] x = new int[ n ];

    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ){

        int value = list[i];
        if( value > v ){

            x[i] = value;
        }

    }

    return x;
  }  

}
```

But it gives me the following results:

```
greaterThan( [ 7 -1 -4 2 1 6 1 -3 2 0 2 -7 2 8 ], 2 ): [ 7 0 0 0 0 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 8 ]

greaterThan( [ 7 -1 -4 2 1 6 1 -3 2 0 2 -7 2 8 ], 7 ): [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 8 ]

greaterThan( [ 7 -1 -4 2 1 6 1 -3 2 0 2 -7 2 8 ], 9 ): [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]
```

So I basically need to remove the `0`s to make the array that contains just the rest!

Comment: Please put some effort on formatting the code.

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8, this can be easily done with `filter()`:

```
static int[] greaterThan(int[] list, int v) {
    return Arrays.stream(list).filter(e -> e > v).toArray();
}
```

This works by turning `list` into a stream, then filtering the elements that are greater than `v`, turning the stream into an array again and returning it.

If you can't use Java 8, or are not allowed to use streams, you can achieve this with `Arrays.copyOf()`:

```
static int[] greaterThan(int[] list, int v) {
    // Create an array with the same length as list
    int[] greaterThanV = new int[list.length];

    // Index to be used in by the greaterThanV array
    int numGreater = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        int value = list[i];
        if (value > v) {
            // Store the value and increment the numGreater index
            greaterThanV[numGreater++] = value;
        }
    }
    // Return an array containing the first numGreater elements of greaterThanV
    return Arrays.copyOf(greaterThanV, numGreater);
}
```

The difference from this to your method is that this uses `numGreater` as the index to the result array (`greaterThanV`) and only increments it when an element is stored. This means that, if your call is equivalent to `greaterThan([7 -1 -4 2 1 6 1 -3 2 0 2 -7 2 8], 2)`, instead of returning:

```
[7 0 0 0 0 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 8]
```

The `greaterThanV` array will contain:

```
[7 6 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

In the end, since we stored three values, `numGreater` will be 3. So when we do:

```
Arrays.copyOf([7 6 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0], 3)
```

We get the trimmed array as result:

```
[7 6 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having is that you are storing the number in the ith spot no matter what. When the input number is greater it moves onto the next index in the array, meaning that a 0 gets stored in that location.

The way I would go about fixing this is by creating a counter that gets incremented only after a number has been added to the output array.

```
public static int[] greaterThan( int[] list, int v){

    int n = list.length;
    int[] x = new int[ n ];
    int counter = 0;                // added this

    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ){

        int value = list[i];
        if( value > v ){

            x[counter] = value;   // changed this
            counter++;            // make sure to increase the counter!

        }

    }

    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know the size of the primitive array before hand, convert to it later.

```
List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
//Code to check and store the elements
for(int i = 0; i<list.length; i++) {
    if(list[i] > n)
      newList.add(list[i]);
}
return newList.toArray(new int[list.size()]);
```